# When printing a check from a business account is it possible to print it on the smaller (personal) check paper?

Tags: united-states, check

My father owns his own business and asked me to print a few checks on the smaller (personal) size check paper? I did not know this was possible, but he assured me that it was. I am confused about how to print MICR line. Do I print it with the check number first (it's a business account) or do I print it at the end (since it's going to be on the smaller check paper)?

Answer (score 5):

Technically it doesn't matter what size the check is. In fact, it doesn't even have to be written on paper. While [writing it on a cow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_of_Inland_Revenue_v_Haddock) may not always fly, [almost any *object*](http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-20434,00.html) actually will.

That said, more to the question asked - you can definitely use the smaller "personal"-sized checks for a business account. The larger checks formatted to the "letter" page size: if you cut it into three equal pieces with a tiny bit left for the binder holes - you'll get exactly three check-sized pieces. This is convenient for those printing checks, keeping carbon-copy records etc.

Regarding the MICR line: I just checked my business check book, which is of a smaller "personal" size (that I got for free from the bank) - the check number is at the end.

Comment: An one would also need MICR ink in printer? or has US moved to OCR?

Comment: +1 especially for the reference to _Board of Internal Revenue v. Haddock._  :-)

Comment: @Dheer I believe MICR ink is not necessarily required, but is very advised. But I believe the OP already has it since he/she's been printing checks before.